# Speed and travel time

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If at speed 0 it takes an infinite amount of time to arrive at a destination, and at speed 100 it takes 86400 seconds to arrive at the destination, how do I calculate the amount of time it takes to arrive at the destination at any given speed? Thanks!

Comment: `at speed 0 it takes an infinite amount of time to arrive at a destination` No, at speed $\,0\,$ you are standing still and will *never* arrive at any destination other than the point where you were to begin with. How is that relevant to the rest of the question, anyway?

Comment: I am just stating the limits of the problem. Sheesh!

Comment: No Sir. First of all, the units of speed aren't given. Second, by your knowledge, it takes an infinite amount of time to go any non-zero distance with speed zero, so that is a nearly useless statement. Nevertheless, at least the answer below is correct, so you can accept that and close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the distance from the formula $v=d/t$, yielding $d=vt$. Now for any velocity $v_1$ you have $v_1=d/t_1$ or $t_1=d/v_1$. You can write this as $$t_1=\frac{v}{v_1}t$$

Answer (score 1):

Speed times time equals distance.  You have what you need to compute the distance, then if you divide by a different speed you get the time at that speed.